# Как правильно тестировать AutoMapper?

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

Продакшен код работает с автомаппером, есть цель протестировать работу автомаппера. Имеется в виду : протестировать правильность маппинга тех или иных сущностей.

Вот что написал я:

```
[Test]
public void MapFromUserToDalUser()
{
    // arrange
    var user = new User()
    {
        Id = 1,
        Email = "kek@cheburek.ru",
        Name = "Birsultan Nazarbaev",
        Phone = "233-655-900",
        SsoId = "myuniquessoid",
        ContactDetails = "shieee",
        Roles = new List<RolesEnum>() { RolesEnum.User, RolesEnum.Moderator }
    };

    // act
    var dalUser = mapper.Map<DalUser>(user);

    // assert
    Assert.AreEqual(user.Id, dalUser.Id);
    Assert.AreEqual(user.Name, dalUser.Name);
    Assert.AreEqual(user.Phone, dalUser.Phone);
    Assert.AreEqual(user.SsoId, dalUser.SsoId);
    Assert.AreEqual(user.Email, dalUser.Email);
    Assert.AreEqual(user.ContactDetails, dalUser.ContactDetails);
    Assert.AreEqual(
        user.Roles.Select(x => (int)x).OrderBy(x => x).ToList(),
        dalUser.DalUserDalRoles.Select(x => x.DalRoleId).OrderBy(x => x).ToList());
}
```

Как по мне - это не особо верный подход написания тестов для автомаппера, т.к. я создаю сущность вручную после делаю маппинг и сравниваю. 
Знаю, что у автомаппера есть возможность автоматически генерить фейк и проверить смапилось ли корректно или нет.
Вопрос в том, как сделать то ,что я сделал вручную, автоматически?

Comment: Для генерилки есть AutoFixture, для коллекций - ColectionAssert, но вообще в чем смысл тестирования автомаппера?

Comment: Ммм ,есть такая проблема, что проект билдится в дженкинсе удалённо и бывают случаи, когда разрабы в команде комитят и пушат что-то рабочее, но это может не работать на билд машине по тем или иным причинам(очень часто было) . Например какая-нибудь функция "подписки" на пост может не работать на билде из-за неправильного маппинга в БД( такое было) , поэтому сейчас дженкинс настроен на то, что сначала прогоняет все тесты, а уже потом билдит. => стейджинг более устойчивый чем до этого => зер гуд

Comment: В целом звучит логично - это единственный способ проверить, что все свойства классов правильно маппятся. Это выглядит странно, скорее всего, потому, что сама модель и маппинг - простые. Возможно, такие маппинги нет и смысла тестировать. Вот если бы каждое свойство в DAL как-то хитро считалось на основе модели, то имело бы смысл. Кстати, для последнего ассерта, вроде бы, нужно использовать `CollectionAssert`. Лично я бы просто не тестировал эту часть (особенно если автомаппер используется напрямую в коде без абстракций), а тестировал бы результат работы в целом.

Comment: @TetsuaKeito "Например какая-нибудь функция подписки на пост может не работать на билде из-за неправильного маппинга в БД". А есть пример того как это не работает? В частности, что за exception был? Быть может, будет просто нет проверки конфигурации маппера `AssertConfigurationIsValid `?

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev По поводу первого коммента : 
Есть более сложные модели, это просто очень простая "создание юзера", но есть гораздо более сложная модель "Категории", где используется древовидная структура , так же есть и модели "Поиска", которые вообще на эластик серче, но это уже другое.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev По поводу второго коммента, тип эксепшена не помню, но в основном трабла в том, что на дженкинсе докер не всегда верно подтягивается(либо миграции криво встают)  и он не всегда пересоздает его => использует старую в бд в которую не накатили миграции => обычный эксепшен с тем, что поля не так замапились как нужно. 
В целом, такой тест как у меня вполне приемлем, но вдруг есть путь как это сделать более эститично, ибо сейчас это похоже на очень костыльный метод

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`AutoMapper` тестировать не надо. Для этого у него есть

```
Mapper.Configuration.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration-validation.html

Если у вас есть сложная функция конвертации, которую вы вызываете при маппинге, то тестируйте конкретно эту функцию.

Comment: Хм...да, скорее всего вы правы.